# UINavigationController nav bar overlaps contained TableView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, arcgis-server

I have a third party control that wants me to put a view inside of it. I'm trying to get a UINavigationController containing a series of table views inside of it, but when adding the controls the navigation bar overlaps the tableview by about half a row, which looks dumb.

Here's the code. I'm using the ArcGIS Server iOS SDK to put the navigation controller in a callout box on the map:

```
    IdentifyResultsViewController *idWindow = [[IdentifyResultsViewController alloc] init];
    idWindow.results = results;
    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:idWindow];
    map.callout.customView = nvc.view;
    nvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 275, 400);

     [map showCalloutAtPoint:self.mapPoint];
```

Is this a common problem using the UINavigationViewController, or should I look to the third party control?

Comment: The navigation bar is opaque and not transparent, right?

Comment: Yep. A little too opaque for something that's sitting over my other controls.

Comment: Well, you could look at the idWindow.view.frame prior to making it the rootViewController and afterwards. Defer (using dispatch_after or with NSTimer) and call a method on appDelegate which looks at the idWIndow.view and walks up the views looking at their frames (via the superview property). Its possible that class is actually calling presentViewController or adding other views to its view - so you may need to walk the subviews to find out which view is "on top".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using some simple reordering of code - instead of using initWithRootViewController, I created the navigation view controller, set it's frame manually, and then pushed the view controller on to it:

```
    IdentifyResultsViewController *idWindow = [[IdentifyResultsViewController alloc] init];
    idWindow.results = [self filterResults:results];
    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    nvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 275, 400);
    [nvc pushViewController:idWindow animated:NO];

    map.callout.customView = nvc.view;
    [map showCalloutAtPoint:self.mapPoint];
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had a similar problem with a third party control obstructing my navigation bar.  I tried to look into the control but I'm not versed enough to unhide the navigation bar.

What I did may be something you can do too: instead of using the built in UINavigationBar, I kind of built one myself by just putting in a UIView at the top of the page and adding custom buttons to it that performed the functions that I wanted in the bar.  This gives you a little more wiggle room around that third party control if you can't find what's causing the issue.

Hope it helps!